# Vlocity Ins package vlocity_ins:DML currently not allowed An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (vlocity_ins)

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity

We have the Salesforce Omnistudio Vlocity Insurance package in Custom Run time. When we are opening the Omniscripts tab, we are getting the below error.[image]

Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: What version of `Vlocity__ins` are you currently using? Can you confirm if there are document records created in this org?

Answer (score 0):

ive faced the same problem. in my case it was in a sandbox that was recently created from prod.. and the weird thing was that in prod it was working fine (with the same user)

I solved it by doing this:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394208&type=1

in case the link dosent work, here are the steps:

**Description**
Omnistudio package is installed.
When attempting to load the Omniscript page we are getting the following
Error - omnistudio:DML currently not allowed An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified. (omnistudio)

Have upgraded and uninstalled/reinstalled but the error persists.

**Resolution**
Switch to Classic Mode. Click on the + sign from the Tab Panel. Search Documents.

- Go to Documents.
- In the Document folders section, click the dropdown list and select 'Vlocity Document Uploads."
- Click New Document.
- Name and Unique Name = VlocityLogoDocumentUploads.
- Attach the sample file [Eg given below] and click Save.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it would bee better if you would reproduce the important parts of it here. Links tend to become invalid over time, and Salesforce in particular doesn't have a great track record when it comes to link longevity.